# Images stitched but color was changed slightly

Tags: python, opencv

Running OpenCV 4.1.0 sample code, image was stitched well, however, compared to the original two images, at the same point, the RGB value was changed. Why did this happen? Is there any solution to keep the original one?

please check the screen shot as below, the left was original one and right was stitched one. RGB value has been changed slightly at the same pixel.

[image]

```py
def main():
args = parser.parse_args()

# read input images
imgs = []
for img_name in args.img:
    img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(img_name))
    if img is None:
        print("can't read image " + img_name)
        sys.exit(-1)
    imgs.append(img)

stitcher = cv.Stitcher.create(args.mode)
status, pano = stitcher.stitch(imgs)

if status != cv.Stitcher_OK:
    print("Can't stitch images, error code = %d" % status)
    sys.exit(-1)

cv.imwrite(args.output, pano);
print("stitching completed successfully. %s saved!" % args.output)

print('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
    main()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe this occurs because of the blending during/after the stitching (especially, if this section is part of more than one image to be stitched). From the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d4a/classcv_1_1detail_1_1Blender.html), it seems, that there are (only) two blending algorithms available. I'm afraid, investigating this route will be a lot of work, but setting the `Blender` to `NO` might be an idea to try.

Comment: Please guide how to try to set Blender to NO, thx.